# Set Russian language on Alcatel Pop S7 (Android 4.1.2)

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, rooting, languages

I am not able to configure the device to Russian language, although assumed that all Android supports it.

Question: What are the chances to enable Russian UI after I root the device? Worth trying or just will not be supported?

Note: I can install Russian language keyboard, but I am looking for Russian UI on the phone itself.

Comment: Just for confirmation, have you checked it on `Settings > Language & input > Language`?

Comment: Yes...CHecked there multiple times and even after factory reset- no RUssian

Answer (score 0):

[MoreLocale 2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.c_lis.ccl.morelocale&hl=en) from the Play Store might be worth a shot.

Taken from the app listing:

> You can select more locales via this app.
>   If your locale doesn't appear, please use custom locale function in menu.

So if you don't see your preferred language in the app, you might have luck specifying something like `ru-RU` in the app's custom locale wizard.